# how to use the_excerpt for two post queries?

Tags: excerpt, genesis-theme-framework, read-more

I am new to Genesis, i created a child theme it has two post types, one for the THEMES i want to display and other for the PORTFOLIO. both of these are having the_excerpt in their loop,

I want to add "View Theme" and "View Project" separately. I also want to control the limit of the excerpt for each one will have more excerpt to show and other will have less. the same filter is applied on both of the post types.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question to state clearer what it is? It sounds like you're asking multiple questions, and so you should ask them in... multiple questions, not one. Doing it this way is incorrect ( and deprives you of reputation points too )

Answer (score 0):

```
function excerpt($limit) {
$excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
array_pop($excerpt);
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
} else {
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
}   
$excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
return $excerpt;
}
```

write below code in your template.

```
<?php echo excerpt(25); ?>
```